# Is it possible to pass values from a query to models.py in django?

Tags: python, django, cx-oracle

I'm trying to make an app in which a person inserts an id and a birthday date of someone and outputs something. My 
doubt here is: having a query (from oracle) with the several id and birthday dates using:

```
connection = cx_Oracle.connect(...) 
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("query")
```

My question is: Is it possible to pass some values from the query to my models.py file? For example, in my "models.py" file I have a field called "id" and I would like to pass all the records from the query in the field "doente" to the "models.py" file as "id".

My form is something like this:
[Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dw80c.png)

and my models.py file is:

```
class PatientTutor(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length = 8)
    patientID = models.CharField(max_length = 8)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    birthday = models.DateField(blank=True, default=None)
    birthdayPatient = models.DateField(blank=True, default=None)
```

where the values from the fields: "GTS do autorizante" and "Data de nascimento do autorizante" are in my models.py and the values from the fields: "GTS do autorizado" and "Data de nascimento do autorizado" come from the query. I would like to copy all the values from the query to my models.py file but I don't know if that is possible.

EDIT:

my views.py file looks like this so for:

```
def mostraFormTutorPaciente (request):
return render(request, 'CartaoCliente/mostraFormTutorPaciente.html')

def TutorPaciente (request):
if request.method == 'POST':

    AutorizanteGTS = PatientTutor.objects.get(id = request.POST['AutorizanteGts'])
    NascAutorizante = PatientTutor.objects.get(birthday = request.POST['DtNascAutorizante'])

    connection = cx_Oracle.connect("....")

    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("select t_doente, doente, nome, dt_nasc, telef1, telef2" + \
            "from gh.sd_doente where doente<>'" + patientID  + \
            "'and nvl(flag_anulado, 'N')<>'S' and dt_nasc >= sysdate-18*365 and (trim(telef1) in (" + inClause + ") or trim(telef2) in (" + inClause + "))")

    registos =[]
    for record in cursor:
        registos.append(record)

    return render(request, 'CartaoCliente/TutorPaciente.html', )
```

Here I try to get the values that came from the post and are in my models.py and when I made the connection to the oracle db I try to get the other values that came from the post.

Comment: Are you deliberately not using Django's ORM here?

Comment: I don't understand how the "models file" is involved here. If you want to add data into a form, you do it in the form class or in the view.

Comment: The models file is involved because the values that are supposed to be written in  "GTS do autorizado" and "Data de nascimento do autorizado" are in my models.py file.

Comment: So you want to migrate the data from an oracle db to the db that power django ?

Comment: My objective here is to present a message when a recepcionist press the button. But the data that she put in the form are in different places as I explained before. I want to know if it is possible to do. Something like the edition I made.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

When the form is posted, you can get the data from the oracle database, and then save it to a model object.

Use this example view to see how it would work:

```
def my_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    form = MyForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        # get the data from the oracle DB
        oracle_data = some_function()

        # create a model object that saves the data
        obj = MyObject.objects.create(
              birthday=oracle_data['birthdate']
              some_other_field=some_value
              )

        # everything worked out, return a response
        return render(request, 'some-template.html')

    # for data was not valid, return an error
    return render(request, 'error-template.html')
```

Comment: What do you mean by  "  # get the data from the oracle DB
        oracle_data = some_function() ?  " It is supposed to do "   connection = cx_Oracle.connect("....")

    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("select t_doente, doente, nome, dt_nasc, telef1, telef2" + \
            "from gh.sd_doente where doente<>'" + patientID  + \
            "'and nvl(flag_anulado, 'N')<>'S' and dt_nasc >= sysdate-18*365 and (trim(telef1) in (" + inClause + ") or trim(telef2) in (" + inClause + "))")

    registos =[]
    for record in cursor:
        registos.append(record)   " here?